# Can Array contain only a single key value pair?

Tags: php

I have declared a method where it will dynamically create a database query string depending on the table my code is something like this.

```
public function checkBeforeDelete($table = array(), $key , $value )
    {
        $tableCount = count($table);
        $queryString = array();
        for($i=0;$i<$tableCount;$i++)
        {
            $queryString[] = "(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $table[$i] WHERE $key = $value)+";
        }
        /***********************************************************
        Convert the array to a string using implode()              
        Remove all commas(,) using str_replace()                   
        Remove the last character of string using substr_replace()
        ***********************************************************/
        $queryString = substr_replace(str_replace(',','',implode(',',$queryString)),'',-2);
        $queryString = 'SELECT ( '. $queryString . ' ) AS sum';
        $sth = $this->dbh->prepare($queryString);
        $sth->execute();
        return $sth->fetchColumn() >= 1;
    }
```

there are chances when $table array() will have only one single value for example

```
$table = array('states');
```

does it still count to be an array. is it alright if an array contains only a single key value pair?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Empty arrays are valid too, ie:

```
$someVar = array();
```

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely.

Test:

```
<?php

$a = array('test'=> 'key');

var_dump($a);


array(1) {
  ["test"]=>
  string(3) "key"
}
```

As you can see, $a is of type array with a length of 1.